# Where can I download pretty extra templates for LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: openoffice.org, templates, libreoffice

Where can I download pretty extra templates for LibreOffice Impress or OpenOffice.org?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find extra LibreOffice templates on the online [LibreOffice Templates Center](http://templates.libreoffice.org/template-center).

[image]

Comment: Need a way to download in bulk :\

Answer (score 13):

1. Open the Ubuntu software center.
2. Search for libreoffice and select the version you want.
3. Look at the add ons a bit down (screenshot).

The screenshot shows libreoffice impress
[image]

There are also a lot of Tempaltes and extensions at Libre office website.For extensions go [here,](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center?getCategories=Impress_Extension&getCompatibility=any&sort_on=positive_ratings&path=/LibreOffice-Extensions-and-Templates/extension-center&portal_type=PSCProject&SearchableText=) and for templates go [here.](http://templates.libreoffice.org/template-center)

Comment: That's useful, but not related to the question

Comment: There is no package containing extra templates. There are OpenGL transitions, which are useful, but they are not templates. If you know of a package name please specify it.

Comment: Read my last comment, there are **NO template addons in the package manager**. Your list is in fact the full one on my system, [here is a screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/SlOs4GJ.png). Again: If you know a name of a specific addon please specify it.

Comment: I didn't go out. I said its useful, the transitions I found were actually quite good! I can't find the alleged templates package, so I asked you, so please answer. You can also say "opps there is none", I won't down-vote you neither because as I said - It was useful, but not related, you don't need to over-protect your answer. Also - I did comment on the other ones, read :)

Comment: @GuySoft Sorry if that came out wrong, I'm on the worst mobile connection in the world. Updated my answer hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget that powerpoint templates work fine in LibreOffice... A Google search for 'free powerpoint templates' will give you loads of results (a search for LO Impress templates is rather disappointing). Just don't forget to then save the template into .odp format :-)

Comment: Here are a bunch of [presentations for non-commercial use](http://www.powerpointstyles.com/) I found using this search suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

In [this webpage](http://spreadubuntu.neomenlo.org/bn/node/269) you'll find a pack with 30+ templates inspired on *Ubuntu*.

Preview:

[image: Ubuntu Templates]

Comment: Its only templates with the Ubuntu logo

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Ubuntu 12.10, the package `libreoffice-templates` has been made available, containing, so far, a few Impress templates.

The contents of the package [for 13.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/all/libreoffice-templates/filelist) are exactly the same as the contents of the package [for 12.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/libreoffice-templates/filelist).