# LibreOffice-Writer Styles/Templates

Tags: libreoffice

I'm looking for different sets of styles (colorsheme, headings, bullet lists, etc...) for LibreOffice. I need, what is called [Themes](http://www.word-2010.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/themes-in-microsoft-word-2010.gif) in MS Office:

I know, styles can't be imported, but actually they can be embedded in templates!

I know how to create/change a style by myself, but I also know how hard it is to create a good looking, coherent style with nice typography, color-palette and spacings.

That's why I'm looking for templates with ready-to-go set of styles.

A very good example for what I'm looking for is [this](http://templates.libreoffice.org/template-center/simple-writer-template/releases/2/template.ott) template:

Sadly, it's the only one I found, yet.

I already checked the repositories templates.libreoffice.org and templates.openoffice.org

Comment: The docs of libreoffice/open office are examples of good typography. Both sets of docs are available in odt. Not exactly templates, but...

Comment: Try this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82884/where-can-i-download-pretty-extra-templates-for-libreoffice-impress . I think it has the answer to your question and might be of help.